Laravel 8 : "validation.required" // app\Http\Controllers\User\UserController.php:42
I make a Profile Edit Function, but when the validation and edit form i'm not fill the password validation and request password. because i won't to include it on profile edit.
this is my Controller
public function update(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => ['string', 'min:5', 'max:255', 'required'],
                'username' => ['string', 'min:5', 'max:255', 'required', 'alpha_num'],
                'email' => ['email', 'string', 'min:5', 'max:255', 'required'],
                'name_business' => ['string', 'min:5', 'max:255', 'required'],
            ]);

            auth()->user()->update([
                "username" => $request->username,
                "email" => $request->email,
                "password" => $request->old('password'),
                "name" => $request->name,
                "name_business" => $request->name_business,
                "role" => 'user_student'
            ]);

            return redirect()->route('user.user.edit')->with('error', 'Berhasil Mengedit User');
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
            dd($e->getMessage());
            return redirect()->route('user.user.edit')->with('error', 'Maaf, Gagal Mengedit User');
        }
    }

but i got this error : "validation.required" // app\Http\Controllers\User\UserController.php:41
my edit view
<form action="{{ route('user.user.update') }}" method="POST">
                                @method('put')
                                @csrf
                                    <div class="row g-4">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label">Name*</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" placeholder="Enter here..." required>
                                            @error('name')
                                                <span class="text-danger fst-italic">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label">Username*</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" value="{{ Auth::user()->username }}" placeholder="Enter here..." required>
                                            @error('username')
                                                <span class="text-danger fst-italic">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mt-3">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label">Email</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="{{ Auth::user()->email }}" placeholder="Enter here..." required disabled>
                                            @error('email')
                                                <span class="text-danger fst-italic">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <label class="form-label">Business Name*</label>
                                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name_business" value="{{ Auth::user()->name_business }}" placeholder="Enter here..."  required>
                                            @error('name_business')
                                                <span class="text-danger fst-italic">{{ $message }}</span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mt-3">
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-3">
                                            <a href="{{ route('user.dashboard.index') }}"class="btn btn-secondary mb-0">Back</a>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next-btn mb-0">Update Profile</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </form>

I Want to fix this without fill the password field, can i?
